# XSL variable Xpath expression for boolean of two child elements in one select

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, saxon

What would be the exact XPath expression  to set a variable this is in a for each of another element. So far I have variable below but I also need to know the amount is greater than 0 to stop further processing can I do this in one select?

XSL so far

```
<xsl:variable name="UM" select="LossPayment/Coverage[contains('UM',CoverageCd)]"/>
<xsl:if test="$UM">
         ....          
</xsl:if>
```

XML

```
  <Parent>
    <LossPayment>
       <Coverage>
           <CoverageCd>TL</CoverageCd>
       </Coverage>
       <LossPaymentAmt>
               <Amt>000009500</Amt>
       </LossPaymentAmt>
    </LossPayment>
    <LossPayment>
       <Coverage>
            <CoverageCd>UM</CoverageCd>
        </Coverage>
        <LossPaymentAmt>
             <Amt>1</Amt>
       </LossPaymentAmt>
    </LossPayment>
  </Parent>
```

Comment: Consider to post the result sample you want to create for the input sample you have presented, then we can suggest an XSLT way of achieving that. I am currently not sure which problem you face respectively which condition you want to check.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The result would if Parent contains a LossPayment with CoverageCd = UM and that element has Amt greater than 0 then UM = true. Thanks for looking

Comment: @MartinHonnen I would use the result to determine whether further processing will be necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
<xsl:if test="/Parent/LossPayment[Coverage/CoverageCd='UM' and LossPaymentAmt/Amt &gt; 0]">
   <!-- do whatever you want -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something like this but couldn't figure out how to get back out of Coverage to check LossPayment on the same node. Nice!

Comment: @JustinCox actually you don't have to :)